# How to dynamic ip set in ssh section on jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, aws-auto-scaling

In the ssh section of a Jenkins job (ssh publisher), I'm trying to configure the private or public IP address of the autoscaling instance. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or other approaches regarding Jenkins.